# Unity генерация меша для спрайта

Tags: unity3d, спрайт, mesh

Как реализовать генерацию меша по границам спрайта в юнити ?

Comment: под спрайт обычно используется quad, такой вам меш нужен? Объясните, ничего не понятно из вопроса.

Comment: @KingPeas я полагаю - обрезать по альфе, только не шейдером а геометрию такую слепить